# Does $\mathbb R^n$ equipped with a sum of Dirac delta measures admit nowhere locally constant continuous integrable functions?

Tags: gn.general-topology, measure-theory

For any point $x \in \mathbb R^n$, denote by $\delta_x$ the Dirac Delta measure centered at $x$.

Let $a_n$ be an sequence of positive numbers with $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$, and let $d_i$ be a countable dense subset of $\mathbb R^n$.

Given a rearrangement $a_{n_k}$ of $a_n$, consider the space $\mathbb R^n$ under the Euclidean topology and the measure $\sum_k a_{n_k} \delta_{d_k}$.

> **Question:** For any given $a_n, d_i$ satisfying the above consitions, does there exist a rearrangement such that the above space admits nowhere locally constant continuous functions that are integrable under the given measure?

*Note: A function is said to be nowhere locally constant if there exists no open set $S$ for which $f(x) = c$ for all $x$ in $S$.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partition $(a_n)$ into two subsequences $(a_n')$ and $(a_n'')$ with $\sum a_n' < \infty$, and partition $(d_i)$ into two subsequences $(d_i')$ and $(d_i'')$ such that $d_i'' \to \infty$. Pair the $a_i'$s with the $d_i'$s and the $a_i''$s with the $d_i''$s. Then any bounded continuous function that vanishes at every $d_i''$ will be integrable.

Comment: Ah, this was much easier than I expected. Slick solution though!

Comment: Thanks! Fun question.